# How do you upload a csv spreadsheet into Big Query without going through the cloud as a new project?

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, upload

How do you upload a csv spreadsheet into Big Query without going through the cloud as a new project?

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery is not a consumer app like Youtube, or Google Drive.

BigQuery is a product of Google Cloud.
And when using Google Cloud you need to have a project, and billing enabled.

Also the CSV must probably need to be placed on Cloud Storage, and imported from there in BigQuery.

BigQuery is great for large data, and it's a tool that needs developer skills.